# Tensorflow 0.7.1 with Cuda Toolkit 7.5 and cuDNN 7.0

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow

I recently tried to upgrade my Tensorflow installation from 0.6 to 0.7.1 (Ubuntu 15.10, Python 2.7) because it is described to be compatible with more up-to-date Cuda libraries. Everything works well including the simple test from the Tensorflow getting started page. However I'm not able to use cuDNN. When running a program using cuDNN, I first get a warning

"Unable to load cuDNN DSO"

and later the program crashes with

```
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:717] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 980, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:73] Allocating 3.30GiB bytes.
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_bfc_allocator.cc:83] GPU 0 memory begins at 0x704a80000 extends to 0x7d80c8000
F tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:204] could not find cudnnCreate in cudnn DSO; dlerror: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so: undefined symbol: cudnnCreate
```

The files I downloaded for the Cuda Installation were

- cuda-repo-ubuntu1504-7-5-local_7.5-18_amd64.deb
  and
- cudnn-7.0-linux-x64-v4.0-prod.tgz

I followed the instructions on the [Tensorflow getting started page](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/get_started/os_setup.html#optional-install-cuda-gpus-on-linux) with the exception of using cuDNN 7.0 instead of 6.5. $LD_LIBRARY_PATH is
"/usr/local/cuda/lib64"

I have no clue why cudnnCreate is not found. Is there somebody who has successfully installed this configuration and can give me advice?

Comment: cuDNN 7.0? I thought [the latest one](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn) is 5?

Answer (score 8):

I get the same error when I forgot to set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `CUDA_HOME` environment variables:

export `LD_LIBRARY_PATH="$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda/lib64"`
export `CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda`

Comment: worked like a charm in ubuntu 16.04 with cuda 8/cudnn5.1 thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am following this instructions to install TensorFlow in archlinux:
https://github.com/ddigiorg/AI-TensorFlow/blob/master/install/install-TF_2016-02-27.md

It seems you need cuDNN v2 or above, which you can get by register for their Accelerated Computing Developer Program, which usually takes 2 days:
https://developer.nvidia.com/accelerated-computing-developer

**UPDATE**: It seems you already have cuDNNv2

Answer (score 0):

The link sent by jorgemf (thank you) describes a Python 3.5 installation and I almost switched to Python 3.5. 
My last attempt with my present installation was to again copy the cuDNN libraries to /usr/local/cuda/lib64.

And it worked! So the problem is solved, although I still don't know why I had it.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04  &&  cudnnV5.0 && Cuda7.5

I got the some error and solve it in another way.
Follow the official get-started page, I install the cudnn with these commands below, which is basically just copy those files into our cuda directory

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html#optional-install-cuda-gpus-on-linux

> tar xvzf cudnn-7.5-linux-x64-v5.1-ga.tgz
>
> sudo cp cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/include
>
> sudo cp cuda/lib64/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib64
>
> sudo chmod a+r /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn*

But after doing this ,if we use ll command to show all the file in "/usr/local/cuda/lib64" and  compare with the origin files

> ll

it seems that those soft links has broken after copy.
so I delete them and create manually, like this:

> sudo rm libcudnn.so.5 libcudnn.so
>
> sudo ln -sf libcudnn.so.5 libcudnn.so
>
> sudo ln -sf libcudnn.so.5.1.3 libcudnn.so.5

after that, execute

> sudo ldconfig /usr/local/cuda/lib64

and it finally worked!

Answer (score 0):

### Errorsolving for windows 10 users:

- Download cuDNN v5.1 Library for Windows 10 from the [cuda site](https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download),
  register if necessary.
- **Copy** the **cudnn64_5.dll** (cuda\bin\cudnn64_5.dll) from that zip
  archive into

> C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing
>             Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0\bin\;

If C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v8.0 is your install PATH
        for the CUDA toolkit.