# cuDNN library not found when building tensorflow example with bazel

Tags: c++, tensorflow, cudnn

I tried to test the tensorflow example, with c++ api, described here: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_recognition#usage_with_the_c_api

I was able to install tensorflow from sources, but when I wanted to build the example with: `bazel-bin/tensorflow/examples/label_image/label_image`
I get this error :

```
ERROR: /home/user/tensorflow_sources/tensorflow/tensorflow/examples/label_image/BUILD:14:1: Linking of rule '//t
ensorflow/examples/label_image:label_image' failed (Exit 1)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcudnn.so.6, needed by bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Sexamples_Slabel_
Uimage_Clabel_Uimage___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcufft.so.8.0, needed by bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Sexamples_Slabe
l_Uimage_Clabel_Uimage___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcurand.so.8.0, needed by bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Sexamples_Slab
el_Uimage_Clabel_Uimage___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

The issue is exactly the same as described here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15029

But the solution is not clear :

> I need configure LPATH to include path of libcudnn.so. Although I
>   put the lib at the standard location.

What is this LPATH variable ? What is the standard location for this library? Because for me actually, it is /usr/local/cuda

I tried to reconfigure many times my tensorflow installation, I exported the LD_LIBRARY_PATH with the correct path to the folder containing the file libcudnn.so.6 but none of these solution worked.

My configuration :

- tensorflow r1.4
- Cuda 8.0
- cuDNN 6.0
- bazel 0.9.0

Comment: I still have the error even after I tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36965792/9219478

Comment: I have something similar with cudnn7 because trying with python to do "import tensorflow" it is looking for libcudnn.so.6